# How to get tags around selected text in a contenteditable?

Tags: range, selection, contenteditable, wysiwyg

I'm trying to do an handler for applying certain formatting style (bold/cursive) at the click of respective button.

In particular, I want to handle selection of text: I want to toggle tags in a selection (tags are combinable).

I tried this way, but I think there should be better ideas. I found the nearest container to selected text, than I found all of its ancestors inside textarea.

```js
    var selection = document.getSelection();
    var selectedText = selection.toString();
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
    
    var firstTag = $("#textarea-ce *:contains("+selectedText+")"); 
    
    
    var currNode = firstTag;
    var newNode = $(document.createTextNode(selectedText))[0];
    var currTagName;
    var currTag;
    var lastTag = false;
    var found = false;
                        
                        
    while (!lastTag) {

        currTagName = $(currNode).prop('tagName').toLowerCase();
        currTag = $("<"+currTagName+"><"+currTagName+"/>")[0];


        if (currTagName != selectedTagName){
            newNode = $(currTag).html(newNode);
        }
        else {
            found = true;
        }

        if ($(currNode).parent().attr('id') == 'textarea-ce') {
           lastTag = true;
        }
        else {
            currNode = $(currNode).parent();
        }
    }   

  currNode = $(textarea).find(currNode)[0];
        var newNodeContent = $(newNode).html();

        if (!found) {
            newNodeContent = "<"+selectedTagName+">"+newNodeContent+"<"+selectedTagName+"/>";
            newNode = $(selectedTag).html($(newNode));
        }


        if (currTagName.startsWith("h")){

            $(currNode).html(newNodeContent);
            range.insertNode(currNode);
        }
        else {
            $(currNode).replaceWith(newNode);
        }
```

I used header (h1, h2,...) displayed as inline for sizing text.

In order to get surrounding tags I tried also with documentFragment (range.extractContents) but after a selection, sometimes it doesn't include tags, but only the text node.

The hardest challenge is to handle the case in which the user selects part of a formatted text and removes one of those tags.

Any suggestion is appreciated.